# Restricted user on debian 7

Tags: linux, debian

I have small dedicated server and I want to create user with restricted permissions, I want him to use only his home directory, I don't want him to look at other folders etc., is there any way? :)

Thanks.

Comment: home directory and sub-directories*

Answer (score 0):

You can use **adduser** command to add new users.

```
sudo adduser username
```

New users are unprivileged by default. This means that new users are only able to read and modify files in their own home directory.

For more information you may visit [this page](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/2/Adding_new_users).